# Save form inputs on Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm creating a Firefox extension that saves all inputs submitted through form fields.

I thought of going through the POST values, but most websites sent POST data for other reasons already. Is there a way to separate these values from values actually sent through a form?

Is there a better way to identify such data?

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to use Content Scripts, you could attach listener events to each input node.

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('input', yourListenerFunction));
```

Save that data as it gets created and call it done once the user presses the Submit button.